# How do I use Document method getElementById() on a html variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm attempting to read the innerHtml of a html tag that is saved as a string value like so:

```
let htmlVar=`
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
   <h1>The Document Object</h1>
   <h2 id="demo">The getElementById() Method</h2>
  </body>
 </html>
`
```

How can I use `document.getElementById("demo")` and then display the value **The getElementById() Method**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert your text into an [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) that you can use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) on:

```js
let htmlVar=`
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
   <h1>The Document Object</h1>
   <h2 id="demo">The getElementById() Method</h2>
  </body>
 </html>
`

const parser = new DOMParser()
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlVar, "text/html");
console.log(doc.getElementById('demo').textContent)
```